# Value of a Variable for Label Name

Tags: vb.net

I am doing a project for my computing coursework. Could really do with some help please.

I want to be able to take a basic line of code like this...

```
   lblSectionsAttempted.ForeColor = Color.Green
```

And basically turn it into this... but this doesn't work:

```
 lblSectionsAttempted(TempInc).ForeColor = Color.Green
```

TempInc is a variable that gets incremented by 1 each time a loop is done.

I have 14 'lblSectionAttempted' labels on my form. And I want to be able to change the fore color of each label depending what the value of the variable TempInc is... So for example:

So when TempInc = 1, I want lblSectionsAttempted1.ForeColor to change

Then when TempInc =2, I wan lblSectionsAttempted2.ForeColor to change

```
 If TempInc = 1 Then
      lblSectionsAttempted1.ForeColor = Color.Green

 Else if TempInc = 2 Then
      lblSectionsAttempted2.ForeColor = Color.Green
```

etc. etc.

However having lots of if statements isn't ideal. Please can someone tell me how I can re word this line of code to make the value of the variable affect what label is changed..

```
 lblSectionsAttempted(TempInc).ForeColor = Color.Green
```

Comment: Concatenate the name with the counter and then use `FindControl` to get that control, cast it to a `Label` and change the fore color.  Is this WPF, WinForms, or ASP.NET?

Comment: Will the changed color always be Green or is it a different color based on the value of TempInc?

Comment: No either red or green depending on the value of TempInc @Supersnake

Comment: @Tim I have literally no idea, all I know is I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 and it's VB.net code...?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your labels are named lblSectionsAttempted1 through lblSectionsAttempted14 then I would create a control array and use that to loop through and update the forecolor of your labels:

```
    ' Create the control array

    Dim oLabelArray(13) As Label

    oLabelArray(0) = Me.lblSectionAttempted1
    oLabelArray(1) = Me.lblSectionAttempted2
    oLabelArray(2) = Me.lblSectionAttempted3
    oLabelArray(3) = Me.lblSectionAttempted4
    oLabelArray(4) = Me.lblSectionAttempted5
    oLabelArray(5) = Me.lblSectionAttempted6
    oLabelArray(6) = Me.lblSectionAttempted7
    oLabelArray(7) = Me.lblSectionAttempted8
    oLabelArray(8) = Me.lblSectionAttempted9
    oLabelArray(9) = Me.lblSectionAttempted10
    oLabelArray(10) = Me.lblSectionAttempted11
    oLabelArray(11) = Me.lblSectionAttempted12
    oLabelArray(12) = Me.lblSectionAttempted13
    oLabelArray(13) = Me.lblSectionAttempted14

    ' Now if you are updating all controls to the color green you can do this:

    For TempInc As Int32 = 0 To oLabelArray.Count - 1
        oLabelArray(TempInc).ForeColor = Color.Green
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Controls.Find():

```
    Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("lblSectionsAttempted" & TempInc, True)
    If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is Label Then
        Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(matches(0), Label)
        lbl.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End If
```