# Is it possible to do this code with less redundancy?

Tags: vb.net, refactoring

I have the following code:

```
If moves.Contains("1") Then
    lblOnes.Visible = True
End If

If moves.Contains("2") Then
    lblTwos.Visible = True
End If

If moves.Contains("3") Then
    lblThrees.Visible = True
End If

If moves.Contains("4") Then
    lblFours.Visible = True
End If

If moves.Contains("5") Then
    lblFives.Visible = True
End If

If moves.Contains("6") Then
    lblSixes.Visible = True
End If
```

I just feel like it is redundant, is there any way to do this without repeating the same statement over and over?

Comment: are the labels supposed to be invisible when Contains is false?

Comment: You could reduce the overall size of the code with things like: `lblOnes.Visible = moves.Contains("1")`.  The number of statements is still determined by the number of labels, though.

Comment: they are default invisible and only become visisble if it contains those numbers

Comment: If you change "Ones" --> "1" (lbl1), "Twos" --> "2" (lbl2), etc, then it would be easier.  Otherwise you'll have to hard-code the names of the Labels in there somehow (like in an Array or List).

Comment: What @David said. The if statements are redundant since you're assigning True or False depending on whether the condition is True or False.

Comment: If your code is working fine as is, and you're just looking for ways to make it 'cleaner', this question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the luxury of renaming your Labels from lblOnes, lblTwos etc. to lbl1s, lbl2s, then it would simply be:

```
For i = 1 To 6
    Me.Controls("lbl" & i & "s").Visible = moves.Contains(i.ToString())
Next
```

Comment: chose you because this is by far the simplest of all the answers

Comment: Be aware that the Labels must be **directly** contained by the form as it has `Me.Controls`.  If the Labels are in a different container, then replace `Me` with the appropriate name such as `Panel1`.  If the Labels span **multiple** containers then use the [Controls.Find()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28118561/2330053) approach which can recursively search the entire Form.

Answer (score 4):

You could e.g. use a look up using a `Dictionary`:

```
Dim map = new Dictionary(Of String, Label) From
{
    {"2", lblTwos},
    {"3", lblThrees},
    {"4", lblFours},
    {"5", lblFives},
    {"6", lblSixes}
}

For Each kvp In map
    If moves.Contains(kvp.Key) Then
        kvp.value.Visible = True
    End If 
Next
```

Other possible ways:

- use the `Tag` property of the controls
- name your controls `lbl_1`, `lbl_2` etc. and loop over all elements in `moves` to find the right control by its name.

Comment: Change kvp.value.Visible = moves.Contains(kvp.Key) and do away with the If statement

Comment: @ChrisFlynn Or use a `Join`: `For Each label In map.Join(moves, Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y, Function(x, y) x.Value)
  label.Visible = True
 Next`

Answer (score 2):

Another example:

```
    Dim lbls() As Label = {lblOnes, lblTwos, lblThrees, lblFours, lblFives, lblSixes}
    For i As Integer = 0 To lbls.Length - 1
        If moves.Contains((i + 1).ToString) Then
            lbls(i).Visible = True
        Else
            ' ... possibly do something in here? ...
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose following idea:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim moves As String
        moves = "1"
        Dim controlName As String
        controlName = "lbl" + moves
        CType(Me.Controls("controlName"), Label).Visible = True
    End Sub
```