# VBA loop for label names

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word table containing **Legacy DropDown List**. There is 11 rows and let's say 4 columns. Each cell contains a **Legacy DropDown List** which puts the count to 11 per column (44 total).

I have to take the data from these **Legacy DropDown List** and put it into **Labels** in another table on another page of the same document.

No problem so far, I made it work though I had to do write it all down instead of using a loop because I couldn't find a way to put a variable in my label name.

I shortened my code to only the first row of the first week (therefore 4 **labels**) because otherwise it would have been too long and there is no need for it to be that way.

Current code :

```
Sub Week1()
'Week 1
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Dom1").DropDown.ListEntries.Count <> 0 And ActiveDocument.FormFields("Dom1").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("Dom1").DropDown.Value).Name <> "Choose a DOM." Then
    lblDom1W1.Caption = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Dom1").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("Dom1").DropDown.Value).Name
End If

If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Sit1").DropDown.ListEntries.Count <> 0 Then
    If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Sit1").DropDown.Value <> 0 Then
        If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Sit1").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("Sit1").DropDown.Value).Name <> "Choose a SIT" Then
            lblSit1W1.Caption = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Sit1").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("Sit1").DropDown.Value).Name
        End If
    End If
End If

If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Int1").DropDown.ListEntries.Count <> 0 Then
    If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Int1").DropDown.Value <> 0 Then
        lblInt1W1.Caption = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Int1").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("Int1").DropDown.Value).Name
    End If
End If

 If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Gram1").DropDown.ListEntries.Count <> 0 And ActiveDocument.FormFields("Gram1").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("Gram1").DropDown.Value).Name <> "Choose a GRAM." Then
    lblGram1W1.Caption = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Gram1").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("Gram1").DropDown.Value).Name
End If
```

So this works. That being said, I would like to loop it so I could have this much code only once instead of having it repeated 11 times per week for 11 weeks.

I already named the labels for them to be easy with a loop. Therefore, their names are all `lblDom1W1` down to `lblDom11W1` for the first week and so on for the other labels (only the last digit changes ( e.i. `lblDom1W2` down to `lblDom11W2`)).

Furthermore, I thought and tried these methods which I thought wouldn't work and didn't :

- labelName & value
- labelName(value)

I looked through this post but I didn't quite understood everything in it and I'm not sure if that's what I need since it's VB.NET and no exactly VBA. [Post I checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116814/value-of-a-variable-for-label-name)

---

## EDIT:

Following user R3uK comment, I tried this but it doesn't work either. I gives me the *Invalid qualifier* for my `leLabelDom.Caption...`:

```
Sub Week1()
'Week1

Dim labelDom As String
labelDom = "lblDom"

Dim week1 As String
week1 = "W1"

Dim leLabelDom As String

For k = 1 To 11
       leLabelDom = labelDom & k & week1
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeDomaine" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Count <> 0 And ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeDomaine" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeDomaine" & k).DropDown.Value).Name <> "Choisissez un domaine." Then
           leLabelDom.Caption = ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeDomaine" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeDomaine" & k).DropDown.Value).Name
End If
```

---

## EDIT 2 - Working:

Started from the user R3uK answer and end up with this code which works. Huge thanks to you R3uK !

```
Sub Remplir()

Dim leLabelDom As String, _
    wDocD As Word.Document, _
    IsHd As InlineShape, _
    leLabelSit As String, _
    leLabelInt As String, _
    leLabelGram As String, _
    semaine As String

Set wDoc = ActiveDocument

If ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.Value).Name = "Semaine 1" Then
    semaine = "S1"
    lblMaterielS1.Caption = TextBoxMateriel.Text
    lblEvaluationS1.Caption = TextBoxEvaluation.Text
End If
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.Value).Name = "Semaine 2" Then
    semaine = "S2"
    lblMaterielS2.Caption = TextBoxMateriel.Text
    lblEvaluationS2.Caption = TextBoxEvaluation.Text
End If
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.Value).Name = "Semaine 3" Then
    semaine = "S3"
    lblMaterielS3.Caption = TextBoxMateriel.Text
    lblEvaluationS3.Caption = TextBoxEvaluation.Text
End If
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.Value).Name = "Semaine 4" Then
    semaine = "S4"
    lblMaterielS4.Caption = TextBoxMateriel.Text
    lblEvaluationS4.Caption = TextBoxEvaluation.Text
End If
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.Value).Name = "Semaine 5" Then
    semaine = "S5"
    lblMaterielS5.Caption = TextBoxMateriel.Text
    lblEvaluationS5.Caption = TextBoxEvaluation.Text
End If
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.Value).Name = "Semaine 6" Then
    semaine = "S6"
    lblMaterielS6.Caption = TextBoxMateriel.Text
    lblEvaluationS6.Caption = TextBoxEvaluation.Text
End If
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.Value).Name = "Semaine 7" Then
    semaine = "S7"
    lblMaterielS7.Caption = TextBoxMateriel.Text
    lblEvaluationS7.Caption = TextBoxEvaluation.Text
End If
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.Value).Name = "Semaine 8" Then
    semaine = "S8"
    lblMaterielS8.Caption = TextBoxMateriel.Text
    lblEvaluationS8.Caption = TextBoxEvaluation.Text
End If
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.Value).Name = "Semaine 9" Then
    semaine = "S9"
    lblMaterielS9.Caption = TextBoxMateriel.Text
    lblEvaluationS9.Caption = TextBoxEvaluation.Text
End If
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.Value).Name = "Semaine 10" Then
    semaine = "S10"
    lblMaterielS10.Caption = TextBoxMateriel.Text
    lblEvaluationS10.Caption = TextBoxEvaluation.Text
End If
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.ListEntries.Item(ActiveDocument.FormFields("ListeSemaine").DropDown.Value).Name = "Semaine 11" Then
    semaine = "S11"
    lblMaterielS11.Caption = TextBoxMateriel.Text
    lblEvaluationS11.Caption = TextBoxEvaluation.Text
End If

For k = 1 To 11
    leLabelDom = "lblDomaine" & k & semaine
    leLabelSit = "lblSituation" & k & semaine
    leLabelInt = "lblIntention" & k & semaine
    leLabelGram = "lblGrammaire" & k & semaine

If wDoc.FormFields("ListeDomaine" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Count <> 0 And _
    wDoc.FormFields("ListeDomaine" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Item(wDoc.FormFields("ListeDomaine" & k).DropDown.Value).Name <> "Choisissez un domaine." _
    Then
        If wDoc.InlineShapes.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each IsH In wDoc.InlineShapes
                If IsH.Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
                    If TypeName(IsH.OLEFormat.Object) = "Label" Then
                        If IsH.OLEFormat.Object.Name = leLabelDom Then
                            IsH.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = wDoc.FormFields("ListeDomaine" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Item(wDoc.FormFields("ListeDomaine" & k).DropDown.Value).Name
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
End If

If wDoc.FormFields("ListeSituation" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Count <> 0 _
Then
 If wDoc.FormFields("ListeSituation" & k).DropDown.Value <> 0 _
 Then
    If wDoc.FormFields("ListeSituation" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Item(wDoc.FormFields("ListeSituation" & k).DropDown.Value).Name <> "Choisissez une situation" _
    Then
        If wDoc.InlineShapes.Count <> 0 Then
                    For Each IsH In wDoc.InlineShapes
                        If IsH.Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
                            If TypeName(IsH.OLEFormat.Object) = "Label" Then
                                If IsH.OLEFormat.Object.Name = leLabelSit Then
                                    IsH.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = wDoc.FormFields("ListeSituation" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Item(wDoc.FormFields("ListeSituation" & k).DropDown.Value).Name
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
        End If
    End If
End If
        
  If wDoc.FormFields("ListeIntention" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Count <> 0 And _
    wDoc.FormFields("ListeIntention" & k).DropDown.Value <> 0 _
    Then
        If wDoc.InlineShapes.Count <> 0 Then
                    For Each IsH In wDoc.InlineShapes
                        If IsH.Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
                            If TypeName(IsH.OLEFormat.Object) = "Label" Then
                                If IsH.OLEFormat.Object.Name = leLabelInt Then
                                    IsH.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = wDoc.FormFields("ListeIntention" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Item(wDoc.FormFields("ListeIntention" & k).DropDown.Value).Name
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
        End If
        
  If wDoc.FormFields("ListeGrammaire" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Count <> 0 And _
    wDoc.FormFields("ListeGrammaire" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Item(wDoc.FormFields("ListeGrammaire" & k).DropDown.Value).Name <> "Choisissez un niveau." _
    Then
        If wDoc.InlineShapes.Count <> 0 Then
                    For Each IsH In wDoc.InlineShapes
                        If IsH.Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
                            If TypeName(IsH.OLEFormat.Object) = "Label" Then
                                If IsH.OLEFormat.Object.Name = leLabelGram Then
                                    IsH.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = wDoc.FormFields("ListeGrammaire" & k).DropDown.ListEntries.Item(wDoc.FormFields("ListeGrammaire" & k).DropDown.Value).Name
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
        End If
                   
Next k

Set wDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @Tomalak It would indeed though I just thought about looping it. Since I'm new to VBA, I guess my first reflex was to use what I knew worked and do it that way instead of going deeper. That's all on me though. Lost a lot of days coding this since it's not the only document I have that way...

Comment: To compile Strings (texts), use `&`, like this `Dim TpStr as String` and `TpStr = "lblDom" & i & "W1"` ;)

Comment: @R3uK I'm gonna try this right away and be back to you on that ! Thanks !

Comment: @Tomalak : yup quite a brain-jacking here, I was trying to debug my own code which wouldn't compile. And I can't edit the comment, but it really is "concatenate strings"

Comment: @R3uK Thing is, I still can't do this :

    `Dim labelDom As String`
     `labelDom = "lblDom"`

And then use it that way :

    `labelDom & k & "W1".Caption =     ActiveDocument....`

Comment: @Tomalak, my bad, I'll change it right away. That's because my names are in french and I tried to switch everything in english but forgot the following S1 (semaine1) instead of W1 (week1). - edit : Done.

Comment: @Tomalak There is no need of such because they are all aligned together. The four in the first row are : `lblDom1W1` , `lblSit1W1` , `lblInt1W1` , `lblGram1W1`. When you go in the second row, it'll be : `lblDom2W1` , `lblSit2W1` , `lblInt2W1` , `lblGram2W1` etc. To be more specific, I only need the Row coordinate since I don't care about the Column coordinate because it is a different DropDown with a **different** bookmark.

Comment: @Tomalak They switch when the number switch to another one (e.i. W2). As of right now, I've done it manually. That being said, for the loop, I was thinking more about doing one per week resulting in only 11 loop of let's say 22 lines max (18 for the code and 4 for two loops) which means 220 lines instead of 8712 lines (4 labels * 11 Rows * 11 Weeks * 18 lines of code for each rows of 4 labels)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get how your naming scheme works. When the labels have two coordinates then the dropdown fields ought to have two coordinates as well. Otherwise it does not work. Either it is `Dom1` to `Dom11` and `lblDom1` to `lblDom11`, or it's something else and you did not explain what the other number in the label name does.

Comment: I'll make you a quick drawing, won't be long (nor beautiful).

Comment: @Tomalak [Paint drawing of the way I named my labels](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/781200Sanstitre.png) - I'll be more precise, maybe I haven't clearly clarify what the number were in my labels names. The first number is the number of the **row**. The second number is the number of the **week**. -**Edit**  I think I get what you mean. In the way I named them, the column ain't a number but the 3-4 letters word after `lbl` (*Dom*,*Sit*,*Int*,*Gram*). So it would make lbl (for label) + Dom,Sit,Int,Gram (for column) + number (row) + W + number (week).

Comment: @Tomalak I find it simple but everybody has their ways of naming thing. That being said, I think the Edit of my last comment might be the answer to this question of yours.

Comment: @Tomalak To be brief, instead of using numbers for the columns, I used the abreviation of what they are reffering to. The first column stands for all the DropDowns about "Domaine", the second column for those about "Situation", the third one about "Intention" and the fourth about "Grammar". There we have the **rows** and **columns** coverred. The **weeks** are only because I need to know in which labels to put the value of the Dropdowns after they submit. Which results of the third dimensions you reffered to.

Comment: @Tomalak "*I have to take the data from these Legacy DropDown List and put it into Labels in another table on another page of the same document.*" Exactly.

Comment: @Tomalak There is 20 comments because you didn't understand something that is not much important. The point is, my question was not about **How to name my labels**. Of that, I do it how I want. My question was rather **How to loop on these labels inserting the loop variable value in them**. So the "badly question" is not bad. The bad part is you comming in, do 20 comments but not proposing any solutions. If you do not have an idea of how to help the person who asks a question, just don't come in, post about half of the 20 comments and then say it's bad. I'd say that you are your "*telltale*".

Comment: @Tomalak It generates 20 comments because my reader didn't understand an information I haven't provided because it was not important for the **question**. I still took on me to explain to you what you wanted to know, even though it was not needed to understand my question and I think I *humbly* did it. Furthermore, I can take critique, but critique comming from someone who blame me for making too much comments answering **his** questions, I find *that* rude, not me.

Comment: @Tomalak And pardon me if I'm wrong but I don't think you had such a solution since it is so called a "bad question" from you and you probably would'nt "*waste your time on me*" like you said. And if you solution was actually ready, instead of posting about my question being bad because of answers to *your questions*, you would have *humbly* post it so it can help not only me but all the readers that might someday be stuck at the same place then I am. Nobody owes me you are right, but I don't owe you either for *your attitude*. I would rather check yours then mine.

Comment: @Tomalak I get your point and I think you get mine. If you indeed had a solution and chose not to post it because of my "*critique*", then I apologize for the readers that might come here and won't see your solution because of my critique. That being said, other then that, I think we can stop posting here since the number of comments is only growing up and we want to avoid that. Right? Good. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your edit, you try to use a property for a String, but **Properties are only for Object variables**.

So, you need to find where are **stored the controls, in InlineShapes** and then loop and filter it to narrow it down to your specific control and change its value.

Here is something that should work or at least is probably close (can't test it) :

```
Sub OuO()
Dim leLabelDom As String, _
    wDoc As Word.Document, _
    wListE As DropDown, _
    IsH As InlineShape

Set wDoc = wDoc

For k = 1 To 11
    leLabelDom = "lblDom" & k & "W1"
    Set wListE = wDoc.FormFields("ListeDomaine" & k).DropDown

    If wListE.ListEntries.Count <> 0 And _
        wListE.ListEntries.Item(wListE.Value).Name <> "Choisissez un domaine." _
        Then
            If wDoc.InlineShapes.Count <> 0 Then
                For Each IsH In wDoc.InlineShapes
                    If IsH.Type <> wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
                    Else
                        'filter on name
                        With IsH.OLEFormat.Object
                            If .Name <> leLabelDom Then
                            Else
                                .Caption = wListE.ListEntries.Item(wListE.Value).Name
                            End If
                        End With
                    End If
                Next IsH
            Else
            End If
        Else
    End If
Next k

Set wDoc = Nothing
Set wListE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: So, what does it says?

Comment: It gives me "*Error 91 - Object variable not set*" on `Set wListE = wDoc.FormFields("ListeDomaine" & k).DropDown`. I'm looking into it but don't get why it's wrong since wListE is instantiate as a DropDown and it is set to be a Dropdown...

Comment: Bonne chance pour trouver d'où ça vient! Je retourne à mon taff à moi mais je surveille ici ;)

Comment: De ce que je pense comprendre lorsque je "Debug" en utilisant F8, Le wDoc = Rien. Par conséquent, je pense que ça dit que la variable objet n'est pas définie, car le wDoc est "vide". J'ai donc définie le wDoc comme étant le *ActiveDocument* (`Set wDoc = ActiveDocument`). L'erreur n'est plus. Par contre, les *Captions* des étiquettes (labels) n'ont pas reçus les données. Je me penche sur ce bout la, mais au moins, voilà l'erreur 91 de réglée.

Comment: De ce que je vois en debug, `IsH.OLEFormat.Object` retourne la valeur dans les contrôles. Si un textBox contient "test" par exemple, `IsH.OLEFormat.Object` retournera "test" et nom pas le nom du contrôle (exemple txtBoxNom). Je me met là-dessus.

Comment: *Ok, je voulais juste te faire un clin d'oeil entre Français, mais il vaut mieux continuer en Anglais parce que les modérateurs n'apprécieront pas trop et ça exclut beaucoup de monde des discussions donc c'est pas top pour toi non plus!* ;)
**Glad the error 91 was almost nothing, but the second issue is more challenging**... I'll try to find something (maybe translate it so that others can step in from there directly ;) )

Comment: I can figure out what is the precise Control that you are working on, and it is the way to found the possible properties to change for the OLEFormat.Object (using the object browser, in VBE press F2). Can you add a screenshot and some details about it?

Comment: Readers, pardon me from switching from a language to another. I'll translate both post from french to english. **First post:** From what I understand from debugging, wDoc = Nothing. Therefore, I set it to *ActiveDocument* (`Set wDoc = ActiveDocument`) and the error is gone. That being said, the labels caption are still empty. I'll try to figure that out but at least the error 91 is gone. **Second post :** From what I see in debug, `IsH.OLEFormat.Object` returns the value in the controls instead of the name of it. (e.i. For a textbox containing "test", it will return "test" instead of the name.

Comment: I think I got it to work, give me 10 minutes and I'll post the code if it works.

Comment: Took me more then 10 minutes but I got it to work. I'll post the code in an **Edit** of my first post because it is too long for a comment. Thanks to you, it's from your solution that I was able to make it work. If you have any questions about the code I post as an Edit to my question post, feel free to ask ;)

Comment: Glad I could help and that you find a way to what you wanted! I'll take a look at your code once you had time to post it! ;)

Comment: Just posted it. Again, I thought it would be as fast as Copy/Paste but no, I had to format each lines. Hope it'll work for future readers ! ;)

Comment: Mkay... `TypeName`, I would have guessed... Try to use Object referencing : `Set ... = ` from the start to improve your code readability, but that was a good work mate! ;)

Comment: Just changed it. Au plaisir mon cher @R3uK ! ;)